# How to rename a file without refactoring?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, how can I rename a Java file without a refactoring? There is only the dialog *Refactor -> Rename*, which is also bound to F2, so the "normal" rename function isn't available.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. If you want to rename a java file, it can affect the class name, so it is considered refactoring. Can you give an example?

Comment: You can temporarily change the source folder into a regular folder (right-click the source folder and choose _Build Path > Remove from Build Path_). [But why would you want to do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: I just want to change the file extension, so that the file isn't included in the build. Commenting out the file's whole content with `/* ... */` is no useful workaround, as this is to much work, if there is already a multi-line comment in the file.

Comment: @matt: I know that in Java the class name is bound to the filename. However, I find it patronizing when Eclipse won't let me change the filename without refactoring, and I have to use an external tool like a file explorer or a terminal.

Comment: I don't understand. You don't want the file to get compiled, so you are going to change the name of the file?

Comment: Why you want to do this? For example, for source folder you can specify an exclude pattern. Please tell us about the X, not about the Y of this [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: In my current case, I just want to temporarily exclude a Java class from being built and being available on the classpath, so I can be sure it won‘t be loaded (via Reflection). Using an exclude pattern (which I would need to configure in Eclipse and in my Gradle build) is much more work than simply changing the file extension. And my workflow is working fine. I just can’t rename the file using the project explorer and thought, that I might have overlooked something, as non-Java-files can be renamed without any issues.

Comment: If the answer to my question is „not supported“, that’s fine. I just wanted to know if I‘m missing something. (I‘m using IntelliJ usually)

Comment: You don't need this extra step you're used to of executing a Gradle build in order to run your application, as Eclipse has its own incremental Java compiler. Just right-click the file and choose _Build Path > Exclude_ and then run your application. That's it. Alternatively you can open the file and uncomment everything via Ctrl+A, Ctrl+Shift+C. Or you can move the file outside of the source folder.